# questions incorrectly tagged with drupal and webforms

Tags: discussion, tags

There are a lot of Drupal questions tagged with [webforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webforms) which is intended to be used for asp.net webforms rather than the drupal webforms module which has the tag [drupal-webform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drupal-webform). If you search for "drupal webforms" using the stack overflow search, you can see that over half of the questions on the first page of the results are incorrectly tagged like this.

1. Should these questions all be edited to give them the right tags?
2. Can it somehow be made clearer to stop it happening so much in the future?

Comment: I see that you are mass-editing them manually. I'm wondering if it makes sense to do this or if it should be done with a script. Kinda fills up the review queue (no idea if this is encouraged or not, though).